# jquery rolling on tooltip - is this a reasonable cross-browser way?

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I want to add a simple tool-tip and was curious if this was a reasonable way to do this or whether there was an easier / better way? Here's a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/trestles/yU3KM/

Basically, I am placing some text positioned absolutely to a relatively positioned image. I have sized it for the image size in question.

I am not a full-time front-end dev and most of the tool-tips seemed lacking. At least I can customize this.

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fine, and a pretty standard way to accomplish such a task. You may find that you need to add a `z-index` CSS property to keep it above other elements on the page. What will make things more complex is when you can't depend on the location of the item you wish to hover over for the tooltip. When you get to that point, the positioning of the tooltip will need to be created dynamically by grabbing the position of the element being hovered.

Comment: thx - yes, I was going to create a couple of these but is there any standard way for determining that position? I tried googling a bit but couldn't come up with anything. thx

Comment: jQuery has a `.position()` method that will give you the element's offset relative to its closest relatively positioned parent. Using that, as well as the `outerWidth()` and `outerHeight()` methods, you can get the exact coordinates and dimensions of the element in question.

Answer (score 0):

As an approach, this makes sense, and gets around the quirky differences in the way the various browsers do tooltips from the title attribute.

but in your specific code, your creating a new markup on each hover, and then only hiding it, so the DOM is actually getting literred with numerous copies of the tooltip that remain hidden.

It would be better to use .remove('.bubble') than hide('.bubble') et al;

Better yet would be to write the bubble in on page load with display:none, then toggle between hide() and show() with your mouseover/out functions.

Comment: thx, that makes sense. I changed the fiddle for hide -> remove. Could certainly just hide and show it too. Was maybe hoping to add more elements in data tags but maybe just writing it out is better. thx for input